# open a .txt file in a .exe program

Tags: python

I wrote a simple program with python. But in a line it's supposed to open a .txt file located in the same folder of exe program, unluckily it doesn't find it!

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *   

def evaluate(event):
  textfile = open('nomi.txt', 'r')
  nomi = textfile.read().split(' ')
  nome = str(entry.get())
  indice = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  for x in indice:
     if nomi[x] == nome:
         if nomi[x]!=nomi[-1]:
             nome2 = nomi[x+1]
         else:
             nome2 = nomi[0]              
  res.configure(text = "dovrai fare un regalo a " + nome2)

w = Tk()
Label(w, text="Il tuo nome:").pack()
entry = Entry(w)
entry.bind("<Return>", evaluate)
entry.pack()
res = Label(w)
res.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

I need to send this .exe to other people and I thought to put the .txt file in a .zip file with the .exe ...but I need it to read the .txt file!

Comment: try using https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html to specify the directory path of the script you are running

Comment: Use os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(\_\_file\_\_)) to get the directory of the python script and then create the fullpath name of the txt file by joining the directory and the txt filename.

Answer (score 3):

`open('nomi.txt', 'r')` will try to open the file in your *current working directory*.

This means that your `.txt` file needs to be in the same folder you are working from. Note that may be different from where the actual script is, which is not relevant here.

Comment: and what if another user without phyton on his machine will execute my exe file? 
Which one will be his working directory? 
My first time with exe files :)

Comment: @CristianaPanzeri this has nothing to do with "exe files" at all, you'd have the very same issue with a plain python script, or with just any other language as well FWIW.

Comment: @CristianaPanzeri about "what will be the current working directory": actually it's the system that sets it for a given process, according various rules that may vary depending on the system itself, the user, how the process is launched etc etc etc. To make a long story short: it can be just anything and you __must not__ have any expectation about it.

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by using askopenfilename to select manually the file I need!

So my code now looks like that, and it works:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def evaluate(event):
    nome = str(entry.get())
    indice = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for x in indice:
        print(nomi[x])
        print(nome)
        if nomi[x] == nome:
            if nomi[x]!=nomi[-1]:
                nome2 = nomi[x+1]
            else:
                nome2 = nomi[0]          
    res.configure(text = "dovrai fare un regalo a " + nome2)

root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select 
file",filetypes = (("txt","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
textfile = open(root.filename, 'r')
nomi = textfile.read().split(' ')

w = Tk()
Label(w, text="Il tuo nome:").pack()
entry = Entry(w)
entry.bind("<Return>", evaluate)
entry.pack()
res = Label(w)
res.pack()
w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the folder the file is located in when you open it.  You haven't provided enough information for me to advise how to determine what the path to that folder is, if you can't just include it directly in the code.

Comment: So I cannot send the program to other people, because they will have the ".txt" file in different path than me...

Comment: @CristianaPanzeri: They'll need to enter the path.  Either as a configuration value the program reads, as a command line argument, as input, etc.  Alternatively, you could search the entire file system for a file of that name.  Kind of slow, and runs the risk of false positives.